# How do you pass a class method as param of deferred.defer on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pickle

Here are my attempts:

```
deferred.defer(class1().method1, class2.method2, arg)
deferred.defer(class1().method1, class2.method2(), arg)
```

Both of these fail with the error:

```
Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: it's not found as __builtin__.instancemethod
```

In another post about how to pickle an instance method, Steven Bethard's solution was suggested: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/552476-why-cant-you-pickle-instancemethods (towards the bottom of the page)

The code has lost its formatting and I have been unable to successfully use the code to solve my deferred problem.

Comment: you shouldn't call the class. try `class1.method1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function to be used in `deferred.defer` must be one that this directly importable, global function. This is because the Deferred handler will almost surely work in different interpreter instance, so the function in question must be imported by it.

If `class1` in your code refers to actual class name, the simplest way to tackle the problem would be wrapping the call to its method inside global function and passing it to `defer`:

```
def deferred_method_call(*args, **kwargs):
    class1.method1(*args, **kwargs)

deferred.defer(deferred_method_call, ...)
```

On the other hand, if `class1` is just a name of variable you point to actual class, you would want to pass it as parameter to your function:

```
def deferred_method_call(class_, *args, **kwargs):
    class_.method1(*args, **kwargs)

deferred.defer(deferred_method_call, class1, ...)
```

This works because class objects (instances of `type`) are picklable and can be passed as arguments to `defer`ed functions.

Comment: What if I am going to use the class instance I am currently on?
For instance, 

```
class foo():
    def bat():
        deferred.defer(defer_function, self)

defer_function(class):
    class.method1()
```

But this will get an unpicklable instance